# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: bluetooth

I instaled Ubuntu 15.04 on a DELL XPS 13 notebook (model 9343, bios A03). My internal bluetooth device is detected with hci, the icon is in the taskbar, but when scanning for bluetooth devices it finds nothing and it itself cannot be found. I am attaching some info. Suggestions are welcome.

```
cribari@darwin4:~$ uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
Linux darwin4 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0019]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c530 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    2.136553] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    2.136568] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.136572] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.136575] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.136581] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.138896] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
[    2.138899] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd not found
[    3.407444] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.407448] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.407452] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.413492] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    3.413499] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    3.413504] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    2.138896] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
cribari@darwin4:~$
```

Comment: I wrote a manual how to install firmware for Broadcom in a legal way. http://askubuntu.com/a/632348/167850

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth not connecting to devices even though it recognizes them](http://askubuntu.com/questions/617513/bluetooth-not-connecting-to-devices-even-though-it-recognizes-them)

Answer (score 6):

Should be pretty easy

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2pb41rhx65t9zi/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd
sudo cp BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

And bluetooth should work

In a few days you should be able to `sudo update-usbids` and your bluetooth device should be identified as bluetooth in `lsusb`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I can now pair bluetooth devices. I paired a DELL bluetooth mouse. It worked but the cursor is very sluggish/erratic. Could that be related to this bug?

Comment: @SuperScript just rename the one in the answer.  Use the wget code to get the firmware and then just `sudo cp BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/fw-0a5c_216f.hcd` for the 3.13 kernels

Comment: @Jeremy31: Whoops, typo.  Can I just rename for the 0a5c-216**a** firmware?

Comment: @SuperScript. Can't rename for that use https://www.dropbox.com/s/sg6wwr82ug7dqe3/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216a.hcd?dl=0