# Broadcom Bluetooth module does not work in Ubuntu 15.04 (Broadcom 216F BT)

Tags: drivers, dell, bluetooth, broadcom

I am having trouble making Bluetooth working on my Dell XPS 13.
Under kernel 3.19 I managed to get it working by using the firmware from the Windows driver (see [here](https://github.com/advancingu/XPS13Linux/issues/1)).

For various reasons I had to upgrade to a 4.x kernel version. Now Bluetooth is not working anymore even with the previous workaround.

The Bluetooth card is a **Broadcom 216F BT**.

---

The output of `lspci` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
[...]
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
[...]
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

---

The output of `lsusb` is

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:4102 Creative Labs 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

The output of `dmesg | egrep -i 'firm|blue'` is

```
[2.253256] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
[2.253259] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd not found
```

---

EDIT 1 :
After running :

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd
```

Bluetooth seem broken and `dmesg | egrep -i 'firm|blue'` output :

```
[    4.257018] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0a0a tx timeout
[   12.259564] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 0a0a failed (-110)
[   14.265142] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   22.267585] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
```

---

Any idea or any solution to make Bluetooth work here ?

Thanks in advance.

For future references I have a *Dell XPS 13 9353 (2015)*

Comment: Post the results of `lsusb` as an edit to your question

Comment: Are there any errors reported in `dmesg | egrep -i 'firm|blue'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: @hg8 Is this resolved?

Comment: No sorry I was not able to access my laptop. I am not able to find ~`VID_0A5C&PID_21D7` @Pilot6 is talking about at step 3 as my card seem to be **0a5c:216f** (see `lsusb`). Am  I missing something ?

Comment: @I updated the download link in my answer. Now you will find the correct firmware. See this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/736384/167850

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/617513/bluetooth-not-connecting-to-devices-even-though-it-recognizes-them

Answer (score 1):

If you already installed the firmware according to the link in your question, just rename the file.

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd
```

It looks like the new kernel module is looking for another file. But firmware is the same.

If you want to use older kernels too, run

```
sudo cp /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-216f.hcd
```

instead. It will keep both files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have renamed the firmware with your first command but now I do not have bluetooth at all... (kernel 4.1.6)

Comment: What does it say in dmesg? And you need to power off and power on the comp.

Comment: I have updated my question. I have powered off my computer (no reboot -turned off, turned on)

Comment: That must be some regression in that kernel that should be reported to kernel maintainers. Why not use kernel 3.19 while it is being fixed?