# Broadcom Bluetooth module does not work in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Dell XPS 13 9343 i7

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, broadcom

I am having trouble making Bluetooth working on my Dell XPS 13 9343, Kernel 3.19.0-50-generic.

The output of `lspci` is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Camarillo Device (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

The output of `lsusb` is

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:5682 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:20d0 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output of `dmesg | egrep -i 'firm|blue'` is

```
[    2.208427] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=1000 lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=220e
[    4.264423] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0a0a tx timeout
[   12.270801] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch command 0a0a failed (-110)
[   14.272434] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   22.276858] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   29.373920] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=1000 lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=220e
[   31.429340] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0a0a tx timeout
[   39.431829] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch command 0a0a failed (-110)
[   41.516546] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   49.518964] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
```

Dell XPS 13 9343
Ultrabook - Intel Core i7 5500 Broadwell, 13.3 "LED touchscreen 3200x1800 QHD +, RAM 8GB, Intel HD Graphics 5500, SSD 256 gigabytes, WiFi, Bluetooth 4.0, USB 3.0, backlit keyboard, Windows 8.1 64-bit MUI (2016)

[image]

Any idea or any solution pls?

Now is `lsusb`

```
[    1.883011] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    1.883030] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.883034] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.883036] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.883041] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    1.896582] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    1.896588] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    1.896593] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    1.945389] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    1.945392] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    1.945396] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    2.027456] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd failed with error -2
[    2.027462] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd not found
```

Comment: Did you install firmware for Broadcom BT?

Comment: I hope so, because the wifi works normally.
Bluetooth function, but only 20%, so I tried to install firmware windows. It did not work.

Then I tried this:

Comment: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/geyslan/configs.git
cd configs/lib/firmware/brcm
sudo cp BCM*.hcd  /lib/firmware/brcm

Comment: There is firmware for another device there. You need to find the correct firmware for YOUR device.

Comment: Where can I find this file? VID and PID
This Done download: bcbtums-win8x86-brcm.inf
MI lsusb output: 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth.

Comment: You can look for a newer Windows driver. But the problem is that most of Windows drivers are not extractable. You will need to install it on some Windows to get the firmware file.

Comment: Please, here I have Windows and I can download. Just do not know exactly what to look for and I can not do hard reinstal. Help me step by step. Thanks

Comment: Find a Windows bluetooth driver that for sure supports your adapter. Install it to Windows and search the system for files BCM*.hex and `bcbtums-win8x86-brcm.inf`. After that use the solution to convert and install the firmware that I gave before.

Comment: Ok, that means that if I have Ubuntu installed on the entire disk, you must reinstall Windows. It is so?

Comment: You can do it on another computer. Or try to find the firmware another way. Maybe someone has extracted it already.

Comment: Find driver with .exe. How do I convert?

Comment: I found the firmware for you. Exe is no good.

Comment: is this?
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=NYRN3&fileId=3426419621&osCode=WB64A&productCode=xps-13-9343-laptop&languageCode=EN&categoryId=NI

Comment: See the answer. Dell provides it in exe format that is hard to extract. I found an Asus driver as a zip.

Comment: Is not it better to wait until April comes the official UBUNTU 16.04 LTS ... and then it solve?
There may be some corrections

Comment: No. There is no way to get Broadcom firmware to Ubuntu because of legal issues. This device is supported but you need to install firmware yourself.

Comment: You can find the converted firmware in this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/617518/167850

Comment: You think to install this:
  Broadcom Corporation - Bluetooth Controller - Micro size USB to Bluetooth Dongle
Last Modified: 6/13/2014
Size: 1.3 MB

Can be Architecture: x86 for 64-bit format?

Comment: You do not need to install anything anymore. You just need to copy the firmware and your built in adapter will work. Have you read my answer below?

Comment: I'll try it according to the instructions you sent:
http://askubuntu.com/a/617518/167850

Comment: NO. That will not work for you. The second command will be different `sudo cp -f BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd`

Comment: wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2pb41rhx65t9zi/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd
sudo cp -f BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb

Comment: If that does not work right away, power off the laptop and power on, not just reboot.

Comment: install like this?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: You're the best !!!! Bluetooth works.
But, you can not connect with the phone. And recognize the phone only when you restart the comp.

Comment: Thus he worked before that, before I tried some fixes

Comment: You needed to restart it once to change the firmware. Did you power off?

Comment: Yes, look up mi mail....new lsusb

Comment: OK. I made a mistake. You have an older kernel. Run `sudo cp /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd`

Comment: You need to rename the file from BCM.hcd to BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd with the prevoius command.

Comment: only this? and power of again?

Comment: Yes. Older kernels require that file name, newer just BCM.hcd.

Comment: WORKS !!!! Just afraid that with the new Ubuntu 16.06, it will be exactly the same, if not worse. Kernel will support 14.00. So setting Bluethoot, Wifi, Tauchpad.

Comment: If you upgrade to 16.04, the other file will be used. So it will be OK. You should have both files now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. I hope I can turn to ask you something, when I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Download [this driver](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BLUETOOTH/Broadcom/ASUS-X99-DELUXE-Broadcom-Bluetooth-Driver-6515800-12009860.shtml#download).

It has firmware for your adapter.

Then convert it using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/632348/167850).

The firmware file for your adapter is `BCM20702A1_001.002.014.1443.1572.hex`.

Convert it to `BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd` and copy to `/lib/firmware/brcm` if you have kernels 3.13, 3.16 or 3.19.

If you have kernel 4.2, convert it to `BCM.hcd`.