# Bluetooth Error

Tags: bluetooth, 16.04

My Bluetooth in Ubuntu 16.04 is unable to find any device.

```
>01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:0918]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0804]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci, wl
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3011 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04d9:a070 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    3.585666] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.585679] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.585682] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.585684] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.585690] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.729392] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.729395] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.729400] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.487158] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    7.487165] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    7.487169] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 5026.726411] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff880251dbad80 failed to resubmit (2)
[    3.142155] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.248765] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin failed with error -2
bluetooth             520192  40 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/617513/bluetooth-not-connecting-to-devices-even-though-it-recognizes-them

Comment: Nope, not even recogniye them .

Comment: See this. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1535802 I don't know why it is not fixed yet :\

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal.

Cut and paste the following commands (all together) and hit enter:

```
pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

You should be prompted for your password.  Enter that.  Exit Terminal.

Should be up and running again.  I think this is some bug in bluetooth.

However, every time you reboot, you will have to run that in Terminal.

I just put it on a sticky note on the desktop and run it after each log in.

Comment: you can put in cron, startup scripts, whatever, so you don't have to run it everytime

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pilot6, the driver for this Bluetooth device:

**Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04ca:3011 Lite-On Technology Corp.**

Is now in the Yakkety proposed kernel, it will be available in Yakkety updates when the verification task is complete.

Before that, you can enable the proposed update on Yakkety to give it a try.

Reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1535802