# Stuttering sound through bluetooth in Ubuntu 16.04LTS with Dell XPS 13 9350

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, xps

I've checked with two bluetooth devices and both are giving me stuttering sound. My bluetooth worked flawlessly with Windows 10. These are the type of things that make Ubuntu not as popular as it could be.

I tried this answer without success:

[After updating to 16.04, bluetooth audio A2DP mode stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775523/after-updating-to-16-04-bluetooth-audio-a2dp-mode-stopped-working)

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/815444/657222) solved my problem.