# Bluetooth not working after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, bluetooth, 15.04

After upgrading from 14.04 to 15.04, my Bluetooth is not working anymore. I don't have the icon in the taskbar. When I go to *Bluetooth* in *System Settings*, it says *Bluetooth disabled*. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? I have attached a few details that could be useful. Thank you in advance.

```
$ sudo rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ sudo service bluetooth status

 bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

$ sudo lsusb; uname -a; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware

Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2232:1024
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1532:0016 Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2516:0020  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux felipe-900X3F 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
bluetooth             491520  3 ath3k,btusb
[    2.140866] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x575f00)
```

Comment: I would blacklist ath3k with `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf`  Reboot and wait about 1 minute then `sudo modprobe ath3k` and see if it will work.  Are there any files listed with `ls /lib/firmware/ar3k`

Comment: @Jeremy31, thank you for your comment, unfortunately, it didn't work. Your command gives: $ ls /lib/firmware/ar3k
AthrBT_0x01020001.dfu  AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu    ramps_0x01020200_40.dfu  ramps_0x31010000_40.dfu
AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu  AthrBT_0x41020000.dfu    ramps_0x01020201_26.dfu  ramps_0x41020000_40.dfu
AthrBT_0x01020201.dfu  ramps_0x01020001_26.dfu  ramps_0x01020201_40.dfu
AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu  ramps_0x01020200_26.dfu  ramps_0x11020000_40.dfu

Comment: did you modprobe either ath3k or btusb to get them to load originally?  I am going to download 15.04 to see if I have any issues as my bluetooth chipset is the same, even though I am using 14.04 with the 4.0 kernel with no issues

Comment: @Jeremy31, no, the bluetoot worked fine after installing 14.04 without any extra configuration. Did you manage to see if it works for you in 15.04? Thank you.

Comment: It did work fine for me on the Live version of 15.04 and was able to pair with my phone and transfer a file.  Any reason not to stay with 14.04?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I made an updated `linux-firmware` with new Atheros firmware. https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/linux-firmware_1.144%2Bar3012_all.deb

Comment: @Felipe can you edit the question to include `hciconfig -a`

Comment: @Pilot6, i installed your updated firmware, but still no bluetooth. @Jeremy31, `hciconfig -a` did not show anything.

Comment: @Felipe There was a similar question lately. It appeared that there was a bad contact with the adapter. OP removed and installed mini-pci module inside laptop and that was fixed. It looks like that may be the case. The adapter is supported but works only sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution in https://askubuntu.com/a/613622/132783 ?

That is:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2pb41rhx65t9zi/BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd
sudo cp BCM20702A0-0a5c-216f.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```