# Bluetooth not working - Ubuntu 15.04 Qualcomm Atheros AR9485

Tags: networking, 15.04, bluetooth, atheros

I have Lenovo G510 with Ubuntu 15.04, and I just don't see the bluetooth
(It did worked it the past)

```
elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ uname -a
Linux Lenovo-G510 3.19.0-30-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 20:58:04 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: b8:ee:65:61:57:f6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.19.0-30-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:b0500000-b057ffff memory:b0580000-b058ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8172 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: f8:a9:63:25:b4:13
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:30 memory:b0400000-b043ffff ioport:3000(size=128)

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo service bluetooth restart

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2015-10-01 11:20:28 IDT; 2s ago
 Main PID: 1294 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1294 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n

Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: bluetoothd[1294]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: bluetoothd[1294]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: bluetoothd[1294]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: bluetoothd[1294]: Failed to init time plugin
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: bluetoothd[1294]: Failed to init alert plugin
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: bluetoothd[1294]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: bluetoothd[1294]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Oct 01 11:20:28 Lenovo-G510 bluetoothd[1294]: bluetoothd[1294]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:114f Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05c6:6765 Qualcomm, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.213404] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    5.659575] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x450f03)

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue

elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ lsmod | grep blue
```

If anyone have any idea how to fix it I would love to hear (I'm willing to even recompile the whole system if you have a patch)
Thanks!

P.S:
I ran `dmesg | grep -i blue` again and now i've found these lines:

```
[    4.780100] usb 1-7: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   16.342944] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[   16.342958] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.342962] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.342964] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.342968] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
```

and running `lsmod | grep blue` came back with new result:

```
bluetooth             491520  2 ath3k,btusb
```

And Bluetooth just got back to rfkill :)

```
elichai2@Lenovo-G510:~$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: File a bug report as you did when you had 14.10, as this seems to be a different issue as the bluetooth is not in the `lsusb` results and your bug report from 14.10 shows it as `ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.`

Comment: I filed a bug report here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1501685

Comment: btw, what do you say about this solution, is it compatible for me? https://askubuntu.com/questions/613614/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-15-04/613622#613622

Comment: Not compatible as you have an Atheros AR3012 bluetooth.  Do you have a ISO for Ubuntu 14.04 that you can try without installing and see if `lsusb` shows the device?  I just booted my Lenovo on a 15.04 ISO and `lsusb` shows the bluetooth device

Comment: amm i'll try (i'll look for USB and install ubuntu on it)

Comment: I have a problem booting from USB because I use Samsung SSD EVO 840, and it's not quite compatible with my laptop(Lenovo G510) so If I try too get into the BIOS settings It's just get stuck on the 'Lenovo' until I get the battery out and leave it for a while and then reboot(and my ubuntu loads)

Answer (score 2):

With the latest edit, all you need to do is open a terminal window and enter

```
rfkill unblock all
```

And if it doesn't fix the bluetooth, it is likely because you don't have firmware installed

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe -r ath3k
sudo modprobe ath3k
sudo modprobe btusb
```